# angular bootstrap tabular data not shown properly

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am creating a panel which shows user data like the following,

```
Name                           XYZ 
Date-of-birth                  DD-MM-YYYY 
Phone Number                   0000000000
Mail                           xyz@abc.in
Country                        MMM
```

The code using angularjs & bootstrap to display this content

```
<div class='row col-md-12'>
                                <span class='col-md-6'>Name</span>
                                <span class='col-md-6'>{{user.name}}</span>
                                <span class='col-md-6'>Date-of-birth</span>
                                <span class='col-md-6'>{{user.dateOfBirth}}</span>
                                <span class='col-md-6'>Phone Number</span>
                                <span class='col-md-6'>{{user.contactNumber}}</span>
                                <span class='col-md-6'>Mail</span>
                                <span class='col-md-6'>{{user.mail}}</span>
                                <span class='col-md-6'>Country</span>
                                <span class='col-md-6'>{{user.country}}</span>
                    </div>
```

Everything works fine as long as all the fields are having proper data. There might be cases like user will not have a mail id. When he does not have mail id `{{user.mail}}` returns empty value and that corresponding `span` is not getting created which makes the following structure while displaying,

```
    Name                           XYZ 
    Date-of-birth                  DD-MM-YYYY 
    Phone Number                   0000000000
    Mail                           Country
    MMM
```

If I use `<table>` then it will work properly, but the page wont be responsive. Is there any way to keep a space with empty data when the user object does not have value for it?

Comment: You can use  'ng-if' if you like

Comment: <span ng-show='user.mail'>
<span class='col-md-6'>Mail</span>
<span class='col-md-6'>{{user.mail}}</span>
<span>

Add a span with ng-show attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can try by condition also . it worked for me

use Ternary Operator as follows:

```
condition ? value-true : value-false
```

as,

```
<span class='col-md-6'>{{user.mail?(user.mail):" " }}</span>
```

Comment: I could understand that we can use ternary operators. but the profile page will have around 50 to 60 fields. So once I write `ng-show` or ternary conditions for all those fields, the code looks very clumsy. So don't we have any other way with less text to achieve this functionality?